# Function in Python to check difference between two dates

Tags: python-3.x

I am learning data science at Udacity. I am counfused about the following Python code.

We have a dictionary

```
paid_students = {}
for enrollment in non_udacity_enrollments:
    if not enrollment['is_canceled'] or enrollment['days_to_cancel'] > 7 :
        account_key=enrollment['account_key']
        enrollment_date=enrollment['join_date']
        paid_students[account_key] = enrollment_date
```

Then we have the following function which takes two dates as argument

```
def within_one_week(join_date, engagement_date):
    time_delta = engagement_date - join_date
    return time_delta.days < 7
```

Now this function clearly takes two dates as argument.

Now check the following code where we are using the above mentioned function (`within_one_week(join_date, engagement_date)`) but one of the arguments doesn't seem like a date to me.

```
paid_engagement_in_first_week = []

for engagement in non_udacity_engagement:
    student_id = engagement['account_key']
    if student_id in paid_students:
        if within_one_week(paid_students[student_id], engagement['utc_date']):
            paid_engagement_in_first_week.append(engagement)
```

Can you tell me why one of the argument is `paid_students[student_id]`, which doesn't seem like a date to me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`paid_students` is dictionary, with `enrollment['account_key']` as keys and `enrollment['join_date']` as values.

So, when you do `paid_student[student_id]` you actually get the value of given key(`student_id`) which is a date acquired from `enrollment['join_date']`.

Comment: plus one -- since you beat me to it and lot a new users never figure out how to select the answer as correct

Comment: Hi @Jonelya, glad it helped. :) Please consider [accepting the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. **Of couse, there is no obligation to do this.**